# Why do I get unauthorized: authentication required from a docker pull from docker hub?

Tags: docker

I've setup a docker up login on the docker hub website.

I've [run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#privileged-user-requirement) `sudo docker login` and put my credentials in.

When I run

```
sudo docker pull sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.7.1
```

It downloads 5 hashes and then I get

```
unauthorized: authentication required
```

and then the pull finishes.

This [person](https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/) can reproduce this issue.

Note that this is different to two similar questions because they're about `docker push` and not `docker pull`.

There is a little bit of chatter here about `docker pull` authorization issues related to `config.json` [format](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3683) and the [UTC date](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2645). I don't see how they're relevant to this situation.

My question is: **Why do I get `unauthorized: authentication required` from a `docker pull` from docker hub?**

Comment: Do you use a proxy to access the internet?

Comment: I don't use a proxy

Comment: That's a typical problem of using a proxy or any kind of connection problem.

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful (if a little counter-intuitive).

Comment: Another issue I faced was - I could not login with my email ID registered with docker, instead I had to put in my username to login

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough - even without a proxy on your mac - Docker for Mac runs through a proxy!

[image]

To switch it off (by default it is on) go to your Docker menu and choose `Preferences` then `Proxies` and change the setting from `Use System Proxy` to `No Proxy`.